# Change broadcast_address of existing YugabyteDB installation

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have a single node Yugabyte 2.12.3 instance setup to use the public server address.
When I try to change services to bind to localhost I can't properly start the master service, I got an error:

```
UNKNOWN_ROLE    
ERROR: Network error (yb/util/net/socket.cc:551):
Unable to get registration information for peer ([10.20.12.246:7100]) id (fad4f3b477364900a15679cd954bf6b5): recvmsg error: Connection refused (system error 111)
```

What is needed to adjust to starting master service normally?
Does this localhost master service have info about the previous node setup and try contacting that master node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think we support changing the bind/broadcast address, after the fact. We persist address information, in various structures, across servers, eg: for each tablet, we store the IP in each raft group.